# How to Publish a Lightning component (Not an application) in AppExchange

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, appexchange, isv

I came up with a section in AppExchange where I am looking at native Salesforce Components alone. These are depending on an application(Main App/managed package) and other some are independent components which can be installed and used in any org. Please use [This link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/components) to navigate to component appExchange.

What I need to know is how to publish individual lightning components to this section?? I know how to publish an App/Complete managed package but what are the steps to publish only one lightning component to AppExchange?

My understanding is that, we might need a managed package to each lightning component that needs to upload in appExchange. Please let me know if I am wrong. 
If Yes, I might need 5-8 managed packages under same namespace. But, we are not using SFDX right now. Please let me know how to approach this situation to publish only one lightning component of an application. NOTE: We are not using Lightning WEB Components.

Comment: Those things you linked to are, indeed, managed packages. Which is why, e.g. Box's one is called `Box Lightning Component Pack for Community Cloud
By Box` (note the word Pack). Basically, if you absolutely want to try to get individual ones out there, you will have to go through the pain of submission and review multiple times. Perhaps you might want to revisit the business goals of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we will be needing extension packages to individual Component and publish them to appExchange. Obviously, we need to go through security reviews as a part of it and it is taking months to finish before giving these products to clients.